# Fit (Adjust W x H of) the images occuring in UIWebview during runtime?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In Uiwebview, During run time images are not fixed our iphone device (**means image scrolled up and down, my clint asked dont want to scroll image. so how can i fit the image our device** ), and even customized buttons also not fixed properly(means its not fit in our device).

**During run time:**
if any images came, those images are not fixed(not fit our iphone device) properly.

can u pls help me if anyone knows... i have been strugling this issue last week onwards.

pls help me.. is it posible to resolve r not?

```
{
        self.webviews.scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
 [webviews loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"path of the URL/"]]];
        webviews.scalesPageToFit =YES;
        [webviews addSubview:indicator];
        webviews.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        webviews.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
        webviews.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0) target:self selector:@selector(MonsterMovies) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
```

Comment: How is this related to `UIWebView`? What's the code that deals with the web content? I only see irrelevant code.

Comment: if you have images in your html code with the url you have specified..then you can use meta tag to fit your html content to fit on your ios device.but if and only if there is html page have images which not fixed

Comment: as said by @H2CO3, no relevant code for web view is there. If you didnt show up the code in your message, you might have to use appropriate css file that resizes your html content as per the device resolution. you might be using the same html for different devices.

Comment: @Venkat You should remove your answer from within the question and post it as an answer and accept it. It will be much more helpful to everybody that way and you will get more potential for reputation as well.

Comment: @Stunner  actually i didn't have much reputations, thats why i sent like this way

Answer (score 0):

## **Venkat's answer:**

Finally I resolve the issue.

**Image Fixing Problem Resolved:**

Actually client given website size --- 320 x 480
but in our app, i partiate the UIwebview 2 parts (like UIwebview and TabBar(like Foeward, Backward and refresh)) -used UIwebview size --- 320 x 437 -and remaining tabbar/imageview size : 320 x 43 so thats the reason only, image getting scrolling option.
**Solution:** We have 2 options to resolve this issue (in my knowledge 1st option is better performance wise, but using 2nd option issue resolved).

**1. need to ask the client, change website size (like our reqired size ex: 320 X 440).**

**2. we can get image(.jpg) file path and insert into UIimageview.**

So I think you understood the problem, why its behaving like this...

**Solution:**

Using content search option, you can find the image(.jpg) file path and if is there any image, display the image on UIImageView. here I have attached code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     NSURL* url = [webView.request URL];
     NSString * strCurrentUrl = [url absoluteString];

     NSLog(@"curretn url is %@",strCurrentUrl);
     if ([strCurrentUrl rangeOfString:@".jpg"].location==NSNotFound)
     {
        notnetImg.hidden=YES;
        NSLog(@"Substring Not Found");

     }
     else
     {
        NSLog(@"Substring Found Successfully");
        notnetImg.hidden=NO;


    notnetImg.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strCurrentUrl]]];


     }
}
```